# Selecting empty array values from a Spark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given a DataFrame with the following rows:

```py
rows = [
    Row(col1='abc', col2=[8], col3=[18], col4=[16]),
    Row(col2='def', col2=[18], col3=[18], col4=[]),
    Row(col3='ghi', col2=[], col3=[], col4=[])]
```

I'd like to remove rows with an empty array for each of `col2`, `col3` and `col4` (i.e. the 3rd row).

For example I might expect this code to work:

```py
df.where(~df.col2.isEmpty(), ~df.col3.isEmpty(), ~df.col4.isEmpty()).collect()
```

I have two problems

1. how to combine where clauses with `and` but more importantly...
2. how to determine if the array is empty.

So, is there a builtin function to query for empty arrays? Is there an elegant way to coerce an empty array to an `na` or `null` value?

I'm trying to avoid using python to solve it, either with a UDF or `.map()`.

Answer (score 3):

> how to combine where clauses with and

To construct boolean expressions on columns you should use `&`, `|` and `~` operators so in your case it should be something like this

```
~lit(True) & ~lit(False)
```

Since these operators have higher precedence than the comparison operators for complex expressions you'll have to use parentheses:

```
(lit(1) > lit(2)) & (lit(3) > lit(4))
```

> how to determine if the array is empty.

I am pretty sure there is no elegant way to handle this without an UDF. I guess you already know you can use a Python UDF like this

```
isEmpty = udf(lambda x: len(x) == 0, BooleanType())
```

It is also possible to use a Hive UDF:

```
df.registerTempTable("df")
query = "SELECT * FROM df WHERE {0}".format(
  " AND ".join("SIZE({0}) > 0".format(c) for c in ["col2", "col3", "col4"]))

sqlContext.sql(query)
```

Only feasible non-UDF solution that comes to mind is to cast to string

```
cols = [
    col(c).cast(StringType()) != lit("ArrayBuffer()")
    for c in  ["col2", "col3", "col4"]
]
cond = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, cols)
df.where(cond)
```

but it smells from a mile away.

It is also possible to `explode` an array, `groupBy`, `agg` using `count` and `join` but is most likely far to expensive to be useful in any real life scenario.

Probably the best approach to avoid UDFs and dirty hacks is to replace empty arrays with `NULL`.

Comment: Useful info thanks. I'd be interested to see an example of replacing empty arrays with `null`. Is there a non-udf way to achieve that?

Comment: Personally I would use Hive `SIZE` UDF or clean data on load.